# why is localhost:5000 denied in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, express

I am following a youtube tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA&t=1125s. In 18:25. "THIS WORK!" should be printed out on the localhost:5000 page, but I am not able to see it. Anyone can help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check your firewall? E. g. windows defender sometimes blocks localhost

Comment: Somebody is serving you a 403.  TLS misconfiguration perhaps?

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a painting of it.

Comment: did you actually run the code? like npm start or something?

Comment: How are you running that code? And do you have some other webserver installed?

Comment: Yurgh, really, [no images of code please](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). I can never understand how people think that making a screenshot, saving the file, uploading the file to a service, getting a URL, then inserting an image in a question is easier and makes more sense than... you know, copy/paste.

Comment: I think it's best to post a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see (as part of the first image is cut off), the problem is probably that you forgot call `app.listen`, which tells express to listen on port 5000.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  // callback when server is up
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a CORS issue. Please try this

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
}));
```

That is because the same origin will always be allowed. If you need to allow requests from everywhere, that should be manually configurated. The code above basically will set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to do so.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) explains in-depth about this. Even if it happens to be not applicable here, it's worth reading.