# same-origin error while working with multer in mern app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, mern

//Error

**GET http://localhost:8080/Uploads/2022-01-05T15-45-33.363Z-portfolio.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200**

*Files and other fields were saved database but I could not fetch the images server while I can reach other fields.*

[image: Error on Browser]

```js
//Server
```

```js
*Client APIs*
const create = async (credentials, restaurant) => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(config.ServerURI + "/restaurants", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.t,
      },
      body: restaurant,
    });
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const list = async (signal) => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(config.ServerURI + "/restaurants", {
      method: "GET",
      signal: signal,
    });
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Multer middleware

const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './Uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')}-${
        file.originalname
      }`
    );
  },
});
const filefilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: filefilter });


//Server
    const create = async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.auth._id;
      let filesArray = [];
      req.files?.forEach((element) => {
        const file = {
          fileName: element.originalname,
          filePath: element.path,
          fileType: element.mimetype,
          fileSize: fileSizeFormatter(element.size, 2),
        };
        filesArray.push(file);
      });
      const { name, location, cost, rating } = req.body;

      const { restaurantId } = await createRestaurant(
        name,
        location,
        cost,
        rating,
        filesArray,
        user
      );

      res.json({ restaurantId });
    };
    
    
  // app.js
  
  require('dotenv').config();
require('express-async-errors');
// const path = require('path');

// extra security packages
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const express = require('express');
// DataBase and Middlewares
const connectDB = require('./db/connect.js');
const {
  rateLimiterUsingThirdParty,
} = require('./middlewares/rateLimiter.js');

// Routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.routes.js');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user.routes.js');
const restRoutes = require('./routes/restaurant.routes.js');

// error handler
const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middlewares/not-found');
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require('./middlewares/error-handler');

const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: '*',
  })
);
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(xss());
app.use(cookieParser());

// API-DOCUMENTATION

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Restaurants API</h1>');
});

// routes
app.use('/api/v1/auth', rateLimiterUsingThirdParty, authRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/restaurants', restRoutes);

app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It's a CORS misconfiguration. By default the server will only accept requests from the same origin. Please read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454087/why-is-localhost5000-denied-in-express-js). Let me know if it works for you. It's a recurring issue in REST APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your solution did not work for me. I already use cors({ origin : true }) . I really do not understand this. I use the same setup in my older projects, but interestingly first time I see this error.

Comment: I've never seen `origin: true`. The specification tells us to use `origin: '*'` .